# What is the mnemonic index in the context of an application menu?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, computer-science

I have a menu bar across the top of my application and each of the menu items has a property on it called `mnemonic index`. It's value is usually -1. The documentation does provide any help. What is the mnemonic index in relation to a menu item and what is it for?

The environment I'm working in is Flex and Adobe AIR. It's a property on the NativeMenu and NativeMenuItem.

Comment: See @SushiHangover's nice answer... See those underlined R, G, B letters in his example? That's a `mnemonic index` of 0. A minus 1 would mean "un-used" or else "not supported by this operating system"...

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. Are you saying the only valid values are -1 and 0? Why is he setting them to 1, 2, 3? Is it similar to tabIndex?

Comment: The index starts at 0 for first letter. `Red` is R=0, e=1, d=2.. I have no idea why he used 1, he will explain later. I've never dealt with -1 but usually it means `null` without using null (eg: not supported or not used). Some OS don't use the mnemonic index ("On a Mac the index is irrelevant since the OS uses the first letter or two of the menu item.." So using underlined _e_ in Blue is irrelevant since _bl_ are automatic mnemonics)

Answer (score 2):

A mnemonic is single key, not used in combination with CTRL, ALT, or SHIFT keys, that activates a menu command in an open menu. They are the character in a menu item on Windows that contain the underscore, i.e. R, G, B:

[image]

Menu item mnemonics only are relevant on Windows, OS-X does not support mnemonics in menu items.

Note: I know on Windows 7 (and under) they are supported, but not sure if they are even supported (show) under Windows 8.1/10:

[image]

[image]

```
    var root:NativeMenu = new NativeMenu();
    var stackRoot:NativeMenuItem = root.addSubmenu(new NativeMenu(), "Stack");

    var stack:NativeMenu = new NativeMenu();
    stackRoot.submenu = stack;

    var overflow1:NativeMenuItem = new NativeMenuItem("Overflow1");
    overflow1.mnemonicIndex = 1;
    overflow1.keyEquivalent = "A";
    overflow1.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectCommand);
    stack.addItem(overflow1);

    var overflow2:NativeMenuItem = new NativeMenuItem("Overflow2");
    overflow2.mnemonicIndex = 2;
    overflow2.keyEquivalent = "B";
    overflow2.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectCommand);
    stack.addItem(overflow2);

    var overflow3:NativeMenuItem = new NativeMenuItem("Overflow3");
    overflow3.mnemonicIndex = 3;
    overflow3.keyEquivalent = "C";
    overflow3.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectCommand);
    stack.addItem(overflow3);

    if (NativeApplication.supportsMenu) {
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.menu = root;
    } else {
        stage.nativeWindow.menu = root;
    }
```